# How can I deploy a Node HTTP/2 server to Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have a regular Node(v12) http server on App Engine. I switched to http2 with `http2.createSecureServer`. It works in development, but deploying to App Engine and after the server starts successfully it responds to requests with 502 bad gateway...

I tried to switch to `http2.createServer` to not use https, and the request never receives a response (forever loading). The last log in App Engine Log Explorer for that request shows:

```
[error] 27#27: *2 upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header 
while reading response header from upstream, client: 
169.254.1.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/"
```

It seems like it somehow is expecting http1, but I don't know why. I also don't know why it's on port 8081, I have the port set to 8080.

After spending my day searching Google and their docs for anything on using http2 with App Engine, I'm burnt out. And, their support page says "post on Stack Overflow"..

#### main.js

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = new (require('koa'))();
const logger = require('koa-logger');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const json = require('koa-json');
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
const router = require('./router.js');
const { PORT, HOST, KEY, CERT } = require('./config.js');

app.use(logger());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(json());
app.use(cors({ exposeHeaders: 'authorization' }));

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

const server = http2
  .createSecureServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync(KEY),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(CERT),
      allowHTTP1: true
    },
    app.callback()
  )
  .listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Koa HTTP/2 running at https://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
  });
```

#### app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12
service: api
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

vpc_access_connector:
  name:

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
  PORT:8080
  KEY: key.pem
  CERT: cert.pem

  ...
```

Comment: Post your app.yaml and source code.

Comment: @JohnHanley I added the relevant source code

Comment: SSL (TLS) is handled for you by the Google Frontend (GFE). Communications between the GFE and your app is HTTP on port 8080. Update your question once you correct your code to use HTTP only. Suggestion. while testing do not use redirect 301.

Comment: HTTP/2 requires SSL, doesn't it? So if communication between GFE and the Node server is HTTP, then HTTP/2 would be converted and I wouldn't benefit from using it. Right?

Comment: All HTTP/2 requests will be translated into HTTP/1.1 requests when forwarded to the application server. HTTP/2 traffic to the backend service is NOT supported.

Comment: Will that affect you? Depends on which HTTP/2 features that you are using. Create a new question for that topic.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but according to the link your previous statement is a *request* limit. I'm trying to *respond* with HTTP/2. It doesn't mention such limits in the "response limits" section.

Comment: Then you cannot use App Engine. If you want control over the TCP/IP stack you need to use Compute Engine.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer - Google App Engine does not support HTTP/2 in any capacity. That's what I could not find anywhere in the docs.

Comment: HTTP/2 is supported on the GFE for your App Engine service. Many HTTP/2 features will continue to work as the GFE handles them for you. Some features will not work so it is case dependent.

Comment: Do you have a link to that I can read about?

Comment: Google has published many documents on its support for HTTP/2. Start with this link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTTP/2 and App Engine together you might consider using [Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/better-load-balancing-for-app-engine-cloud-run-and-functions) with your serverless applications. A **502 Error** in Google App Engine might refer to several different possibilities.

**Error message BAD_GATEWAY**

An error code 502 with `BAD_GATEWAY` in the message usually indicates that App Engine terminated the application because it ran out of memory. The default App Engine flexible VM only has 1GB of memory, with only 600MB available for the application container.

**Error code 502 or 503**

App Engine may take a few minutes to respond successfully to requests. If you send a request and get back an HTTP 502, 503, or some other server error, wait a minute and try the request again.